# Determining distance between two points along line feature in one direction using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop

I have three  layers, two different point layers and a line feature. The line feature is representing a river system, and one set of points shows monitoring sites along the river (purple markers) and the other shows dams and impoundments (red circles).

I would like to calculate the downstream distance between a dam and the closest monitoring station. This is a small subset of a larger river system. Ideally I would be able automate this process for ~100 dam to monitoring station distances and get a distance for each downstream station, not only the closest one (i.e. a situation in which there are two monitoring stations that are downstream of a dam). The points do not exactly intersect the river system, and most are within ~1000 m.

[image: River network]

Comment: If you seek help on how to do this using ArcPy then please include a code snippet that illustrates what you have tried and where you are stuck.

Comment: RivEX has a [tool](http://www.rivex.co.uk/Online-Manual/Findsitesdownstreamofasite.html) that can do this. You would need to snap your points to the network, RivEX has a [tool](http://www.rivex.co.uk/Online-Manual/Snapsitestonetwork.html) for that too.

Comment: There is even a [mini video](http://www.rivex.co.uk/Online-Manual/VideoWalkthroughs.html#FindDS) you can watch showing the output of tool

Comment: Thanks Hornbydd, I appreciate the suggestion. Ideally this could be done without buying a RivEX license. The purpose of this analysis was to use publicly available data to see if there were any areas downstream, that might be suitable for more detailed monitoring. I was hoping to use some available ArcMap tools.